# mock-maker-inline makes other mocks not work

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, cglib

I tried out the `mock-maker-inline` "Incubation" feature of Mockito to be able to mock a final class (problem described and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592818/mocking-a-class-with-transactional-method-with-mockito)). Since then other tests fail with:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

when I define an exception to be thrown by a spy.
Relevant code from one of the tests:

In @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public MessagePersister messagePersister() {
    return Mockito.spy(new MessagePersister(...));
}
```

Note: MessagePersister is proxied by CGLIB.

In Test class:

```
@Inject
private MessagePersister messagePersisterSpy;

@Test
public void exceptionInPersisterTest() {
    doThrow(new SomeException("exceptionFromTest")).doCallRealMethod()
            .when(messagePersisterSpy).persistMessages(any());
...
}
```

The exception is understandable. The class of `messagePersisterSpy` is `MessagePersister$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c49f1e2`, but if I remove the `mock-maker-inline` feature, my spy is of class `MessagePersister$MockitoMock$515952708$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9523b504` and the tests are green.

Any ideas where this interference comes from and if I can do something about it ?

Thank you !

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... Could you finally find a workaround/fix? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: @teemoo Sorry, but I don't remember exactly. As I don't find any use of `mock-maker-inline` in the project, I guess I dropped it all together and redesigned the test / code.

Comment: @teemoo figured out any solution?

Comment: @M-sAnNan nope, sorry, I think I also decided to rewrite the code to test it in a more regular way with standard Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

Found the [solution](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#53) after a lot of digging: specify the [mock maker](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.10.0/org/mockito/MockMakers.html) explicitly for the classes that are not getting mocked as expected.

```
// using annotation
@Mock(mockMaker = MockMakers.SUBCLASS)
Foo mock;
// using MockSettings.withSettings()
Foo mock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class, withSettings().mockMaker(MockMakers.SUBCLASS));
```